# ESLint doesn't warn me on unused vars or components not imported (NextJs TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, eslint

ESLint doesnt warn me on unused vars also it happens with components not imported. I tried every post out there and i'vent any solution :/

disclaimer: i know im not importing navbar for example....Why ESLint doesnt warn me? thanks !

.eslintrc.json

```js
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2020": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "standard",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
        "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
        "prettier/standard",
        "prettier/react"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier", "react-hooks"],
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "error",
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "space-before-function-paren": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["off"]
    }
}
```

also my index.tsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'

const data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'artfol', url: 'http://google.com', alt: 'artfol' },
    { id: 2, name: 'FAQ', url: 'http://google.com', alt: 'FAQ' }
]

const Home: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <main>
                <Navbar />
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Does ESLint warn you about anything? It might just not be working at all. Also typescript is supposed to throw errors on using unknown components. Does it do that?

Comment: @apokryfos i tried to make some mistake and it doesnt warn me anything, my ESLint output gives me this [Info  - 9:53:59 AM] ESLint server is starting
[Info  - 9:54:00 AM] ESLint server running in node v12.18.3
[Info  - 9:54:00 AM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 9:54:01 AM] ESLint library loaded from: /Users/axelvaldez/Documents/Repositorios/artfol/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js

Answer (score 1):

Well i found the error. Prettier merged every extends into "prettier" so my code looks like this

```js
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "standard",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "react": { "version": "detect" }
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "space-before-function-paren": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  }
}
```

Also eslint gives me an error due React unused var so i comment this

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
import React from 'react'
```